# Html popup window, the parent should have no access

Tags: html, popup, window

I'm trying to create a popup() where user clicks on button, then it triggers window where he does some edit.

While the user is editing in the child window, parent window should not be accessed, it should be blocked.

How exactly should i do this?

This is what i'm doing now.

function Popupwindow()
{
    name = "Select Requestor";
    url = "selectLocation.html";
    options = "height=330, width=210, location=no, scrollbars=yes,menubars=yes,toolbars=yes,resizable=yes,left=0";
    window.open(url,name,options);

}

So now i'm able to close parent window and even edit parent elements without closing child window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use "real" popups, use javascript to "emulate" them in teh same window. take a look at [jquerys dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), where you can also set the modal-mode ([example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) and [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)) - i think this is what you want.

there are a lot of standalone-js examples out thre if you're not using jquery and a lot of js-frameworks include things like this - just search for "modal dialog".

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called a modal dialog. There's no standard way to do this across multiple browsers, some don't even have anything like it. Your best bet is creating a modal dialog inside the page. Most JS frameworks/toolkits will provide dialogs.